# A Drobo, Time Machine, and lots of missing data

Tags: time-machine, backup, data-recovery, drobo

I have [a Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/) connected to my Mac. It has been used for storing large video files, keepsakes and other miscellaneous data. I also use it as a Time Machine backup drive.

Today, I went to look for some files and everything but my Time Machine backups are gone. I am at a complete loss and don't know what to do. I know I should have backed-up my Drobo to another disk, but didn't have a disk big enough.

Does anyone know what could have caused this and if there is anything I can do to figure out what was deleted or even recover the data?

Thank you.

[EDIT] I have noticed that files added to the Drobo just a day or two ago are also partially missing. I believe I have a corrupt volume. I am running DiskWarrior to verify the disk.

Comment: Are any of the drives dead or calling for replacement?

Comment: Not at all. Drobo dashboard shows all is good. I added an edit to my question with new findings.